# Python Nested Loop _ Help Needed

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am  unable to understand this. I just started learning python and confused with loops

```
def sequence(low, high):
    # Complete the outer loop range to make the loop run twice
    # to create two rows
    for x in range(___): 
        # Complete the inner loop range to print the given variable
        # numbers starting from "high" to "low" 
        # Hint: To decrement a range parameter, use negative numbers
        for y in range(___): 
            if y == low:
                # Don’t print a comma after the last item
                print(str(y)) 
            else:
                # Print a comma and a space between numbers
                print(str(y), end=", ")
```

The following should print the sequence 3, 2, 1 two times, as shown above.

```
sequence(1, 3)
```

This should print the sequence 3, 2, 1 two times, as shown above.

```
sequence(1, 3)
```

Unable to understand what to write in the range and how nested loops function

Comment: As all developers do every day, start by taking a look at the documentation. See here for [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) and here for a [loops tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What exactly are you getting?  More importantly, what exactly does ```range(___):``` do?

Comment: Have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

the code you are looking for is this. And I will explain why in the code comments.

```py
def sequence(low, high):
    # range works by putting the number of times you want it to run inside of it
    for x in range(2):
        # (argument1, argument 2, step) this means, Go from high, to low. low-1 is used because range will include everything up to the last argument, so including a -1 will allow you to include the last item. The -1 means go down by 1 each time.
        for y in range(high, low-1, -1):
            if y == low:
                # y == low will check that the y in the range is the lowest, if its not then it will run again. Once it is the lowest, it will print the string. The range by the way is defined by the sequence(1,3) we put at the end. If you change the numbers, it will change the range.
                print(str(y))
            else:
                # Print a comma and a space between numbers
                print(str(y), end=", ")
sequence(1,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops are simply loops within other loops. In this case, you have an outer loop that is responsible for the number of rows you want to print, and an inner loop that is responsible for printing the sequence of numbers in each row.

For your code, you want to print the sequence from `high` to `low` two times. Following is the updated code:

```
def sequence(low, high):
    # Complete the outer loop range to make the loop run twice
    # to create two rows
    for x in range(2):  # Loop will run two times, creating two rows
        # Complete the inner loop range to print the given variable
        # numbers starting from "high" to "low"
        # Hint: To decrement a range parameter, use negative numbers
        for y in range(high, low-1, -1):  # Loop will run from "high" to "low" with a step of -1
            if y == low:
                # Don’t print a comma after the last item
                print(str(y))
            else:
                # Print a comma and a space between numbers
                print(str(y), end=", ")

# Call the function to test it
sequence(1, 3)
```

Output:

```
3, 2, 1
3, 2, 1
```

Here's what the code does:

1. The outer loop `for x in range(2)` will run twice because the range is set to `2`. This will create two rows of the sequence.
2. The inner loop `for y in range(high, low-1, -1)` will run from `high` to `low` (inclusive) with a step of `-1`. This means that the loop will start at `high` and decrement by `1` until it reaches `low`.
3. The inner loop will print the numbers along with a comma and a space, except for the last number (which is `low`). The last number will be printed without a comma.

When you call the function `sequence(1, 3)`, it will print the sequence `3, 2, 1` two times, just as you wanted.